# Reading and Writing a large multi-dimensional array to binary file and back into array during execution?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, binaryfiles

I have a large multi-dimensional array:
float largetable[32][256][128][3]

Is there a way to write this array to a binary file and read it back to the array easily in C++?

In VS2013 when I have the data array in a header file (which is not great form)
but get a :
fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space

So I figure reading it in and out is the way to go.

I'm a python programmer, so I'm relatively new to C++

Comment: Yes there is and I suppose it's pretty easy. Which part of its implementation you can't solve? (to read as: please if you need help first try your own then come here with code and specific questions).

Comment: Try searching for functions named... Um, I dunno... Perhaps `read` and `write`?

Answer (score 1):

use the fwrite() function to write the entire array in one shot:

```
FILE* pFile = fopen("filename", "wb");
fwrite(largetable, sizeof(largetable), 1, pFile);
fclose(pFile);
```

reading it back:

```
FILE* pFile = fopen("filename", "rb");
fread(largetable, sizeof(largetable), 1, pFile);
fclose(pFile);
```

Comment: This is all great, is there a way to add compression too the BIN file was still large?

Comment: can you compress it too?

Comment: Use can use a compression library (e.g. zlib) and pass sections of the large buffer in a loop. Since you now treat the 2D array as a simple 1D buffer, it's no different than compressing any other data.